# What is the best way to implement char const *const names[] in Python

Tags: python, ctypes

I need to pass the "**char const *const names[]**" parameter to C API. How do I get constant pointer to a constant char in python ctypes ?

I tried using
string1 = "Hello First"
names = ctypes.c_wchar_p(string1)

Api call from C would be:
char const *const names[] = { "AVeryLongName", "Name" };

Answer (score 1):

You should start by looking at [[Python 3.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes). Couple of ideas:

- You can't specify *const*ness (or at least, I'm not aware how) via *CTypes*. A small example on *Win*:

  > ```py
  > >>> from ctypes import wintypes
  > >>> wintypes.LPCSTR == wintypes.LPSTR
  > True
  > ```

  So, the *CTypes* wrapper for your array is same as for `char *names[] = ....`
- Starting with *Python **3***, the (*8* bit) *char* sequence (`ctypes.c_char_p`) is no longer a *str* object, but a [[Python 3.Docs]: Built-in Types - Bytes Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects). It has most of the regular string functionality, but when you declare a literal, you have to prefix it with a *b*:

  > ```py
  > >>> s = "Some string"
  > >>> type(s)
  > <class 'str'>
  > >>> b = b"Some string"
  > >>> type(b)
  > <class 'bytes'>
  > ```

  **Note**: To convert a regular string to *bytes*, use [[Python 3.Docs]: Built-in Types - str.**encode**(*encoding="utf-8", errors="strict"*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode): `"Dummy string".encode()`
- An unsized array (*char**) can't be done from *Python*; there are 2 workarounds:

  1. Declare a sized array
  2. Declare a pointer (of type: `ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p)`)

  Let's look at a short example for ***#1.***:

  > ```py
  > >>> ARRAY_DIM = 2
  > >>> CharPArr = ctypes.c_char_p * ARRAY_DIM
  > >>> CharPArr
  > <class '__main__.c_char_p_Array_2'>
  > >>> names = CharPArr(b"AVeryLongName", "Name".encode())
  > >>> names, names[0], names[1]
  > (<__main__.c_char_p_Array_2 object at 0x000002E6DC22A3C8>, b'AVeryLongName', b'Name')
  > ```

  The *names* object (above) is *OK* to be passed to a function that accepts an `char const *const names[]`, although I'm not sure how will the function determine how long is the array (unless another argument holds its length).

  #### Update *#0*

  The same thing for *Python 2*:

  > ```py
  > >>> ARRAY_DIM = 2
  > >>> CharPArr = ctypes.c_char_p * ARRAY_DIM
  > >>> CharPArr
  > <class '__main__.c_char_p_Array_2'>
  > >>> names = CharPArr("AVeryLongName", "Name")
  > >>> names, names[0], names[1]
  > (<__main__.c_char_p_Array_2 object at 0x7f39bc03c5f0>, 'AVeryLongName', 'Name')
  > ```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will try with Python 3.

Comment: You're welcome:) Let me know how it works. I didn't see any *Python* version, so I assumed it's 3. For *Python 2* it's simpler since you can ignore the 2nd bullet.

Comment: CristiFati, actually at the beginning I was trying with Python 2. but once I figured out, I will update my solution.

Comment: I don't understand. What solution? Doesn't this work? So at the end are you using *Python 2* or *3?

Comment: I am using Python 2 and Solution has been updated, Thanks a lot for pointer to the ctypes pointers :)

Comment: OK, you should have also placed the *C* code in the question, I would have prepared an example when I first wrote my answer.

Comment: Sorry CristiFati, I just created the sample code to figure out this issue between Python and C. but Thanks  a lot!. I will keep in mind to have the sample example at first place.

Comment: using `b'string'` solved my problem. The extension is requesting the type of 'char const *'.

Answer (score -1):

This is How I end up implementing and it seems worked with Python 2.7.

Sample C file:

```
void sam_test(char const *const names[],int n)
{
 int i;
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     printf ("%s \n", (names[i]));
   }
}
```

Python:

```
import ctypes
lib = ctypes.cdll['./test.so']
sam = lib['sam_test']
String = ctypes.c_char_p * 3
ii = String("First", "Second", "Third")
name = ctypes.cast(ii, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p))
sam(name, 3)
```